# Change digits for SSN with jquery

Tags: jquery, replace, digits

I found this script to hide digits for the SSN. I would like to accomplish what the blur/focus events do by toggling a button too (and for the text on the button to change as well). I attempted to do this with a Click event, but need help. Can someone please take a look at the fiddle.

I would also like for the HIDDEN state to show the last 4 digits of the SSN and the VISIBLE state shows all digits.

```
HTML
<form>
<input name="ssn" id="ssn" type="text">
<button id="submit">Show SSN</button>
```

```
jQuery          
var retrieveValue = function(ev){
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.data('value');

    if (val) {
        $this.val(val);
    }
},
hideValue = function(ev){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.data('value', $this.val());
    $this.val($this.val().replace(/^\d{5}/, '*****'));
};

$('#ssn').focus(retrieveValue);

$('#ssn').blur(hideValue);

$("#submit").click(function () {
    // check the visibility of the next element in the DOM
    if ($(this).text("Hide SSN")) {
        $('#ssn').val(retrieveValue);
        } else {
       $('#ssn').val(hideValue);
       $('#submit').text("Show SSN");
    }
});
```

Click [here] (http://jsfiddle.net/squirc77/wEwYz/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much easier way of achieving this and it involves toggling the `<input>` from text to password

[JSFidlle 3 text fields](http://jsfiddle.net/a47QC/2/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="ssn1" id="ssn1" size="2" maxlength="3" style="text-align:center;" value="555">
&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="ssn2" id="ssn2" size="2" maxlength="2" style="text-align:center;" value="55">
&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="ssn3" id="ssn3" size="2" maxlength="4" style="text-align:center;" value="5555">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="ssn_button" value="Show/Hide SSN">
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Page has loaded, hide SSN1 and SSN2
    $('#ssn1, #ssn2').attr({'type':'password'});

    // Listen for Focus on any three fields
    $('#ssn1, #ssn2, #ssn3').on('focus', function(){
        $('#ssn1, #ssn2').attr({'type':'text'});
    });

    // Listen for Blur on any three fields
    $('#ssn1, #ssn2, #ssn3').on('blur', function(){
        $('#ssn1, #ssn2').attr({'type':'password'});
    });

    // Show/Hide SSN click
    $('#ssn_button').on('click', function(){
        // Alternate SSN1 and SSN2 based on current SSN1 state
        if($('#ssn1').attr('type') == 'password'){
            $('#ssn1').attr({'type':'text'});
            $('#ssn2').attr({'type':'text'});
        }
        else{
            $('#ssn1').attr({'type':'password'});
            $('#ssn2').attr({'type':'password'});
        }
    });
});
```

**Just for you OP :)**

[JSFiddle 1 text field](http://jsfiddle.net/39nYQ/1/)

Comment: However, I need to display the last 4-digits when the page loads and when the user enters the SSN. The user needs to be able to see the entire SSN when clicking a button, and then click again to revert to the first view.

Comment: @squirc77 This is going to be very tricky with a single `<input>` field. If you are willing to split the SSN into 3 separate `<input>` fields then it will be 100x easier. If you do keep the single `<input>` field then you will have to account for users that do not fill in the entire SSN and then move on in the form. Let me know if you would like a solution involving 3 `<input>` fields.

Comment: yes, I would really like to see the solution using 3 <input> fields. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is great! However, a lingering question. I figured out how to put the 'edge' file on my page to make this work. Is there a way to make it work without it? With IE8? We still supports IE8. Thanks!

Comment: @squirc77 The `edge` jQuery file on JSFiddle simply refers to the latest jQuery build which should be 1.10.2 from http://www.jquery.com and you can actually download the file from their site and include it on your site or you can link to the Google API version like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` and it should have no problem running on IE8 because any 1.x version supports IE8 but if you were to use 2.x then it supports only IE9 and up.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you currently using?

Comment: Thank you for the Edge explanation. I did replace my file with the google link you provided and it works great in both IE versions. I hope others find this script, it is so useful! Made my day! THank you!!!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you have it working now. I'm personally glad you chose to go with 3 `<input>` fields because I truly think it simply looks better and as a bonus it is easier to code exactly what you need.

Comment: I was able to get it all working with one input, using the button & blur/focus to toggle states. added the answer to show that it is actually easier to use one input, and no need to change type to password.

Answer (score 0):

Use Css -webkit-filter: blur. It makes much easier to accomplish with real blur effect.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEwYz/22/)

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input name="ssn" id="ssn" type="text" class="show"/>
    <button id="submit">Hide SSN</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.blur{
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#ssn").toggleClass(function(){
        if($(this).attr('class')=='blur'){
            $('#submit').text("Hide SSN");
            return 'show';
        }else{
            $('#submit').text("Show SSN");
            return 'blur';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I really like your solution but OP's comment on my post says that they want the last 4 digits to be visible now. Do you know if there is there a non-webkit blur effect?

Answer (score 0):

**one input that only accepts numbers**

```
var ssn = $('#ssn'), sub = $('#submit'), stored = ssn.val(), go;
//only if stored has value and button says show, store ssn and toggle
function vshow() {if (stored && go) { ssn.val(stored); cblur(); }};
function vhide() {
    if (!go) {//only if button says hide
        stored = ssn.val();//set stored
        if(stored) {//if stored has value
            if (stored.length>4) {//check length
                ssn.val(Array(stored.length-3).join('*')+stored.slice(-4));
                cblur();//toggle
            }
        }
    }
};
function cblur() {
    sub.text(sub.text()=='Show SSN'?'Hide SSN':'Show SSN');//toggle
    if (sub.text()=='Show SSN') { go=true; }//show
    else if (sub.text()=='Hide SSN') { go=false; }//hide
}
ssn.blur(function() { vhide(); })//on blur
.focus(function() { vshow(); })//on focus
.keyup(function() {
    if (ssn.val().match(new RegExp('[^0-9]','g'))) {//if non-digit present
        ssn.val(ssn.val().replace(/[^\d]+/g,''));//remove non-digit
    }
});
sub.on('click', function () {
    if (go) { vshow(); }//show
    else { vhide(); }//hide
    return false;//prevents default behavior / remove to get it back
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/G36E3/

**EDIT:** added error reporting/validation to fiddle

Comment: I would really like to see this work. When I enter a 9-dig number it hides the whole number. I need it to replace the first 5 numbers with the *****.

Comment: If you focus the text field and activate a `blur` by tabbing or clicking anywhere else in the browser such as white-space then it breaks. For future reference: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/G36E3/

Comment: @squirc77 got it all working, and added validation on the fiddle. let me know what you think. I also replaced the regex you had to make it only show the last 4 numbers, so if there's 5 numbers, it only makes the first an `*`.

Comment: @FiLeVeR10 - This is another great solution! I can follow most of the script and will study it to learn. I also need a script like this to use with a Drivers License. Modifying this script, how would I allow Letters and any length? Should I add a new question for this? Thank you!

Comment: @FiLeVeR10 - I figured out the solution by studying the Regexp, I needed to change it to this to allow the string to start with a number or letter ... thank you.if (DL.val().match(new RegExp('\w[a-z0-9]','g')))

Comment: @squirc77 awesome, and you just change the `maxlength` on the input field to allow more characters